# TeamCity Manual Build Delay

Tags: teamcity

I'm hoping someone has a solution for this but I would like to start a TeamCity build after 5/10 minutes to give my QA team enough time to get out of the system. However I also want to be able to kick it off immediately if there is an issue. I have transitions from Jenkins and this previously was included as part of the Build Paramters `build?delay=0sec`this would allow me to update the seconds for the delay. Is there anything like this in TeamCity? Any fancy hacks anyone has come up with?

I have thought about a shell script that would just call the rest api with the build i want to trigger and the time to delay.

I have though about creating lambda function as well to use the rest api.

However I would like to be able to do this from the website and just delay the build after clicking that button but not have the build taking up a agent for all of those minutes and instead just be delay queued.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure TeamCity has a setting to handle this directly. VCS Quiet Period settings won't allow you to manually start the build immediately, otherwise they would be a good fit.

You can work around this with a thin build configuration, we'll call it CI-Trigger:

CI-Trigger configuration:

- has no build steps
- has the target VCS attached
- has a VCS trigger with appropriate Quiet Period settings

Build-System configuration:

- has a finished build trigger targeting CI-Trigger
- has the target VCS attach
- builds/deploys whatever system in question, does whatever other steps you currently have defined
- does *not* have a formal dependency on CI-Trigger, only the finished build trigger

When a commit is made, CI-Trigger will pick up the change and wait for the specified quiet period. Once that period is up, it will trigger this configuration, which has no build steps, and finish very quickly. Because Build-System is set to trigger when CI-Trigger finishes, it should start.

The effective result is Build-System is delayed by roughly the Quiet Period setting of CI-Trigger.

If you need to run a manual build without quiet period, trigger Build-System directly. No wait time

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach: add [user parameter](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration) to the build, which would indicate timeout, say *DELAY_TIMEOUT*. Set default as you like, say 600 for 10 minutes. Add build step with `sleep %%DELAY_TIMEOUT%%`.

Now, by default clicking on `Run` button would execute your build with default timeout. But you can trigger build with `Run...`, which would let you redefine this parameter and change default value.

Comment: This was my planned implementation. Although this will affect the prediction of the complete time of the build. But oh well I guess you can't have everything...

Comment: There is a big down side to this. If you add a 5 minute delay using sleep. It means that build agent is unusable for 5 minutes as it sits and waits for the sleep to finish.